# Scale with fixed border size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is there any way of keeping border size fixed while scaling an object with CSS?

I have an object with style below

```css
.myObj{
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
   border:1px solid red
}
```

When I scale this object the border of this object also scales as normal. But how can I keep it at 1px?

```js
$(".box").hover( function () {
    
    $('.box').transition({ scale: 4.0 });
}, function () {
    $('.box').transition({ scale: 1.0 });
});
```

```css
.box {
    margin: 20%;
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: #064c73;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GJJp4/61/)

Comment: Inspected the element .. that is actually 1px in scaled version .. so i guess you requirement cannot be implemented with scale

Comment: Thank you for answers but I have to use css transformations and JavaScript. Fiddle was only for a simple demonstration to show the problem.[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/GJJp4/73/) is some part of my actual script.

Comment: My answer uses jquery and why is it a must to use css transformations?Any reason?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'd have to transition the width and height ( and whatever else you need ) instead of using `scale`.

```css
.box {
  transition: 1s;
}

.box:hover {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GJJp4/65/

Comment: the whole point is not to animate width and height properties as they are expensive

Comment: Agreed but a requirement is a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

This problem could however be solved using CSS3 properties only.
But, this would only be possible if you give a 'border-width' of '2px' at first and then change it to '1px' as you hover over it as 1px is the smallest unit value to render with.

```css
.myObj { border: 2px solid red; }

.myObj:hover { border: 1px solid red; }
```

Here goes the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GJJp4/67) for better understanding.

Answer (score -1):

Of course it is possible! I think the easiest way is to change your jQuery code and use the .animate-function instead of the .transition-function:

```
$(".box").hover( function () {
    $('.box').animate({height: 300, width: 300, marginLeft: '-=' + (300-75) / 2, marginTop: '-=' + (300-75) / 2});
}, function () {
    $('.box').animate({height: 75, width: 75, marginLeft: '20%', marginTop: '20%'});
});
```

With a little bit of creativity you'll have the same effect with a thin border ;)

http://jsfiddle.net/GJJp4/71/

Comment: That's not CSS scale, but a workaround to not use scale.

Answer (score -1):

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GJJp4/71/)

```
$(".box").hover( function () {
    $( ".box" ).animate({
         width: "300px",
height: "300px"
}, 100, function() {
// Animation complete.
});

}, function () {
    $( ".box" ).animate({
         width: "75px",
height: "75px"
}, 100, function() {
// Animation complete.
});
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Im late to this answer, but I hope it helps. 
When using css scale, dimensions also scale. You can override this using jQuery (or javascript if you will)

```
var scale = 0.5, /*value of your scale, as in transform: scale(0.5)*/
  absoluteSize = 1/scale + "px" 
  //absoluteSize = 1/0.5px = 2px
$(".box").css("border", absoluteSize);
```

This is pure math 
1/0.5 = 2 
1 = 2(0.5) 
1 = 1

Comment: Pd: the smallest size borders in css are rendered is 1px